# Change User ID and Group ID that is used for Writes on Website (WordPress)

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx, centos, file-permissions

How do you change the User ID and Group ID that is used for writes on a given website?

**For example:** When I upload an image using WordPress it creates an image in the upload directory and the resulting ownership is apache:apache. Is there a way to change this and is there a way to change this on a per site basis?

The ironic part is I am running a CentOS 7 server, **NGINX**, MariaDB and PHP setup. I don't understand where, how or why it is choosing the user and group apache and I would love to know why and how to change it.

Thanks for your time guys, I appreciate it :)

Comment: What user is nginx running as?

Comment: Haha thats the funny part, it is user: nginx. Just to clarify, I run: vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and it has: user: nginx

Comment: ... Wait, centos. I had to setup a different user for php-fpm on my system. what user is php-fpm running as?